# Do I need an empty slot in my Zen garden to get new water or night-time plants?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I'm trying to fill up my night-time and water gardens in Plants vs. Zombies.  My regular Zen garden is completely full, and I know that when I picked up plants from dropped presents while in game previously, they would default to the regular Zen garden.  Then I had to move them to their proper garden with the wheelbarrow.

If there aren't any open slots in my Zen garden, will any water or night-time plants ever drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your zen garden is full, you won't get any more plant drops since water/night drops go to your regular zen garden.